# The application status in weblogic 12c remain "prepared"

Tags: oracle, webserver, weblogic12c

I have deployed an application on weblogic 12c and all the deployment successful while I am trying to run the application the application status changed to "start running" after a while it changed to prepared.

how I can change that application status to Active?

Comment: There are many things than can go wrong. Maybe the application has set the "restart" flag and won't start until you restart whole WL server. 
Anyway to get any hint of what is going on, check your the log file from AdminServer.

Answer (score 3):

You have to select the deployments and select service all requests from start dropdown.
In 12c you will find this option in control tab of deployments summary page.

[image]

[check this out](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/03-DeployApps/deployapps.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Check all data sources bound to this deploy.
If there is a connection error, your deploy can revert to the 'prepared' state